# Creating a log-frequency axis spectrogram using specgram in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I was wondering whether this feature has been built-in via specgram which I believe isn't the case. If not, then the best possible way to implement this using specgram or via matplotlib. If some transformation of the specgram axis can enable this feature.

For example with specgram plots the below won't work(any audio signal can be passed as first argument of specgram):

```
fig = figure(11)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.specgram(tidig.train_symbol_list[0].audio,Fs=12000)
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the scaling of axes using the [`Axes.set_xscale`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale) and `Axes.set_yscale` functions, which both accept either `linear`, `log` or `symlog` as input. So to change a plot to have a log-scaled x axis you would do something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ha = plt.subplot(111)

# Plot your spectrogram here...

ha.set_xscale('log')
```

**Edit** This seems to be a [known issue](http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg16620.html). There are the commands available to do this but not in any particularly convenient way (it should just be a flag to the `specgram` function or `set_xscale` and `set_yscale` should work). However, there is a way to do this:

Instead of using `matplotlib.pyplot.specgram` use [`matplotlib.mlab.specgram`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.specgram). This computes the spectogram but *does not draw it*. You can then use `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor` or a similar function to plot the spectogram. So try something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

# Set up your data here...

Pxx, freq, t = mlab.specgram(x) # Other options, such as NFFT, may be passed
                                # to `specgram` here.

ha = plt.subplot(111)
ha.pcolor(t, freq, Pxx)
ha.set_xscale('log')
```

Comment: It does not seem so easy... when I test this, it raises an error, whether I call the set_xscale before or after calling specgram.

Comment: I tested this on Python 2.6 with matplotlib 1.0.1 and it works (although I just plotted a line rhather than a spectogram). What error do you get. As ever, it is useful to include some code in your question showing exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm not the one who asked the question, I just wanted to find an answer, so I have downloaded the specgram_demo.py and tried this, and finally got a ValueError. However I'm using Python 2.6.5 with matplotlib 0.99.1.1...

Comment: @Chris That doesn't work with specgram plots. I run the current repository at 1.1.0 and python 2.6.5 currently. I know how to change on other plots the axis. Specgram uses an image I believe so can't just change the axis like that. I believe you need some sort of image transformation. I think this capability is available I'm just not sure how to implement it correctly. I added relevant code above so if you can get it working like that then let me know. For the audio just put in any sine wave or import a section of a wav file using scikits.audiolab

Comment: This seems to be a know limitation of matplotlib, it should be easier to do than it is. It can be done however, see my edit.

Comment: @Chris - Cheers, I'll look into that today or tomorrow. I knew that you could plot it seperately but wasn't sure what to plot the output with but hopefully pcolor works. I'll let you know what I find out.

Comment: @Chris - This produces a really low resolution image compared to the specgram. I can't figure out how to change that. Also the extents of Pcolor when in Log mode appear to have to fall on the exact base 10 values (eg, the extent is from 10**3 to 10**4)

Comment: Well the other alternative is to modify the `Pxx` values. See for example the functions `plot_specgram` and `specgram` in [this](http://spikepy.googlecode.com/svn-history/r294/trunk/spikepy/plotting/signal_utils.py) script for example.